# можно ли установить несколько CMS на один локальный Open Server

Tags: wordpress, cms, opencart, openserver, localhost

Одновременно необходимо иметь и Wordpress и Opencart(использую для двух разных сайтов),могу ли я на одном лок.сервере держать две CMS?

Answer (score 2):

Да, можете. Создаете два домена и на каждом держите нужную вам CMS

Answer (score 1):

Да, Вы можете установить хоть 10 разных CMS. Возьмем к примеру OpenServer. В директории `domains/` создаете:

- wordpress/
- opencart/
- magento/
- prestashop/
- webasyst/

Для каждого из этих локальных доменов создаете в phpMyAdmin БД и подключаете её к своему локальному сайту.

У XAMPP все точно также, только там не `domains/`, а `htdocs/`

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток.

Open Server именно тем и славится, что позволяет Вам настроить Вашу локальную среду необходимым для Вас образом.

Хосты:
В зависимости от настроек OpenServer (далее OS) вы можете создать новый хот просто добавив папку в /domains/

[image: структура папки]

Либо вручную добавить его воспользовавшись тулбаром в трее (не забудьте после этого перезагрузить OS)

[image: настройки локальных хостов]

Здесь же вы сможете сконфигурировать и остальные настройки сервера необходимые для Ваших проектов и переключатсья между ними всего парой кликов.

[image: настройка среды разработки]

Желаю Вам успехов!